# non-interactive ssh session does not terminate, sshd process waits forever after a script exits

Tags: linux, ssh

We run a simple deployment script remotely using a command like `ssh deployer@10.170.4.11 sudo /root/run-chef-client.sh`. It started to hang today because `sshd` waited forever on the `10.170.4.11` even after `sudo` had finished already. We started `sshd` in debug mode and got two different kind of logs. The following is a normal log when the session does not hang:

```
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 23187
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 23187
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
Received disconnect from 10.170.4.6: 11: disconnected by user
```

And when it hangs we get the following:

```
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 24209
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 24209
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
```

Our understanding is that the server process waits for some communication from a client side and never gets it. It's hard to tell if it is a client side or a server side problem.
We tried to run `sshd` under `strace` but did not succeed because a SUID bit on `sudo` was ignored it this case. So, what else should we try to debug/prevent this situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ssh -t` (forced PTY allocation) on a client side solved the problem:

```
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 31701
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 31701
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
debug1: session_pty_cleanup: session 0 release /dev/pts/1
Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: PAM: closing session
debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
```

`sshd` is controlled by a pseudo TTY not by a client anymore.