# OpenSSH server on Windows refusing to work without STDIN even in noninteractive mode

Tags: windows, ssh

(related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/836331/182307))

When using sshd server ([Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH)) on windows (with key-based auth for automation), it doesn't work unless it has STDIN (or PTY). For example, running this (from Debian Jessie openssh client) works OK (returning windows username):

```
ssh -4 -T -o Batchmode=yes winserver whoami
```

However, those two do not (they simply terminated without executing command and without returning any output):

```
ssh -4 -T -o Batchmode=yes winserver whoami < /dev/null
ssh -4 -n -T -o Batchmode=yes winserver whoami
```

This presents problem as it is impossible to run non-interactive ssh commands from programs which do not have open STDIN (like **cron(8)** or **atd(8)**).

When using Debian openssh server, it of course works without any problems. Problem only happens with windows ssh servers (Fails with [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) and [FreeSSHD](http://freesshd.com/). [Bitvise SSHD](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) however seems to work OK, but we're looking at gratis solutions for windows ssh servers; open source, simple and maintained are bonuses)

This has been [reported](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/556), but does anybody have solution or workaround in the meantime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the end, I've written this ssh wrapper to work around buggy windows OpenSSH servers which require STDIN even for noninteractive commands which do not use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $HOSTNAME = shift;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($HOSTNAME);

my ($in_pipe, undef, undef, $pid) =
    $ssh->open_ex( { stdin_pipe => 1 }, @ARGV) or die "open_ex failed: " . $ssh->error;

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

It only uses hostname and command with arguments to run, no other parameters are allowed (I set them in `~/.ssh/config`), so you run the script (for example) as `myssh winserver whoami < /dev/null`. It is just a wrapper around ssh client, which provides fake STDIN, and thus allows noninteractive ssh sessions to be run from **cron(8)** and **atd(8)**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Matija-Nalis for the question and solution.  For other's gain, here's a crude python implementation.

ssh.py

```
import sys
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(sys.argv[2], username=sys.argv[1])
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(sys.argv[3])
errlines = stderr.readlines()
outlines = stdout.readlines()
for l in outlines:
    print l.rstrip()
if len(errlines):
    print "WARNING: stderr generated:"
    for l in errlines:
        print l.rstrip()
exit(stdout.channel.recv_exit_status())
```

`python ssh.py <user> <hostname> <command>`

My use case was similar: Jenkins job failed to execute remote commands.